# How do i capture text between two string values?

Tags: regex, string, asp.net-core-2.0, c#-7.0

## The Problem

I have a hobby project that has the aim to sync multiple calendars by requesting the ics file from persons calendars in a group, for the optimal time to plan a meeting. Some sort of lazy way to schedule meetings :)

But i got stuck on reading the ics file for two reasons:

1. I don't really understand Regex.
2. And i don't know how to achieve my goal with string manipulation.

The ics file is already structured, so i know that i want to start from `BEGIN:VEVENT` and gather the that text down to `END:VEVENT`.

I want every event to in a later stage become a class so i can read the data and come up with a decision to present for the end user.

## Background

I tried the regex expression: `BEGIN:VEVENT(?:[\w\s\:\@\.\;\-\=\ä\å\ö\\\,\/\#]*)END:VEVENT` but that is not a very valid approach. Because it gathers all of the the events and does not divide them into separate groups.

I have been using regexer.com to test my regex expression.

## Not code but what i work on

This is some of the text from the ics file:

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20121220T180000Z
DTEND:20121220T190000Z
DTSTAMP:20190503T064840Z
UID:SomeHash@google.com
ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;CN=Name;X-NUM-GUESTS=0:mailto:MailAddress
CREATED:20121212T061002Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20121212T061003Z
LOCATION:ALocation
SEQUENCE:1
STATUS:TENTATIVE
SUMMARY:SomeText
TRANSP:OPAQUE
CATEGORIES:http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#event
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20121213T143000Z
DTEND:20121213T153000Z
DTSTAMP:20190503T064840Z
UID:SomeHash@google.com
ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;CN=Name;X-NUM-GUESTS=0:mailto:MailAddress
CREATED:20121212T061146Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20121212T061146Z
LOCATION:ALocation
SEQUENCE:1
STATUS:TENTATIVE
SUMMARY:SomeText
TRANSP:OPAQUE
CATEGORIES:http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#event
END:VEVENT
```

## Desired outcome

Is to get a array of matches with the string text so i can split it even more and create classes.

## Disclaimer

As this is a hobby project i want to take on a challenge and not use a plugin or helping library. But links to these are appreciated if i can see how they solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using
BEGIN:VEVENT([\s\S]*?)END:VEVENT

I use Regex101.com for regex, Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are usually a good fit for extracting text. But in this simple case you could try something like this:

```
var preambleLenght = "BEGIN:VEVENT\r\n".Length;
var text = ics.Substring(preambleLenght, ics.LastIndexOf("\r\nEND:VEVENT") - preambleLenght);
```